# How to created category on rails app with hmt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to create a category in my blog.I have a post and category model, and post may be somewhat categories.For example: sport, animals, policy, etc.

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :post_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :post_categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_categories
  has_many :posts, through: :post_categories
end
```

and third model post_category.rb

```
class PostCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category
end
```

post_params class method post.rb

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :description, :user,
                               :categories_attributes [:name,
                                                            :category_id])
```

and when I tried to created a form, I don't understand how make it

```
h2 Create
    = form_for @post do |f|
      = f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Title', class: "form-control"
      = f.text_area :body, :class => "redactor", :rows => 40, :cols => 120
      = f.fields_for :categories do |c|
        = c.check_box :category
      .pull-right
        = f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-success"
```

How make it?

Comment: wht's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

To use `HTML` tag add % as `%h2`

```
%h2 Create
= form_for @post do |f|
  = f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Title', class: "form-control"
  = f.text_area :body, :class => "redactor", :rows => 40, :cols => 120
  = f.fields_for :categories do |c|
    = c.check_box :category
  .pull-right
    = f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-success"
```

you should be able to do something like this, not pretty sure for your second question on category

```
= f.fields_for :categories, category do |category| 
    = check_box_tag "post[category_ids][]", category.id, @post.categories.include?(category)`
```

Comment: emm, not the error, but the fact that I have not rendered checkbox with category name.and `%` to do with, I used `slim`

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get, can you try typing in again what you want exactly. SO I can help

Comment: I want a create `category` checkbox on the view